# showing all results from an api call

Tags: python, api

I recently made an api server that searches queries that you input and lists them out. However on the web page it only lists one instead of all of them. Can someone please review my code and help me out?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#imports
import os, sys; sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..", ".."))
from pattern.web import Google, Bing, asynchronous, plaintext
from pattern.web import SEARCH
from pattern.server import App
from pattern.server import MINUTE, HOUR, DAY
from pattern.db  import date


#variables
app = App("api")
#license keys#############################################################################
Gengine = Google(license="AIzaSyBsfFfxX7IIRC3cG0biFnC_8a4eVbp_DBI", language="en")
Bengine = Bing(license="M92rB8xqUqop9UDWfT9GXIbLSODjkQMYM8mMwjWx398=", language="en")
##########################################################################################

#API Search
@app.route("/search", limit=100, time=HOUR, key=lambda data: app.request.ip)
def Search(q=""):
    #print q
    for i in range(1, 2):
        for result in Gengine.search(q, start=i, count=10, type=SEARCH, cached=True):
            print result.title.upper()
            print plaintext(result.text) # plaintext() removes all HTML formatting.
            print result.url
            print result.date
            print

            title = [result.title]
            text = [plaintext(result.text)]
            url = [result.url]
            date = [result.date]

    return {
    "title": title, 
    "text": text
    }

app.run("t0mbst0n3", port=8080, threads=100, queue=50)
```

Answer (score 1):

`return` ends the function, so your loops never get beyond a single iteration. Instead you should collect the values in a list, then return that list at the end of the function.

Comment: So how would I put all the data into a list and then read that list?

Comment: Looks like you are having trouble with very basic topics. I suggest you do an introductory Python tutorial.

Comment: Maybe I should brush up on it. I forgot certain things.

Comment: I can't return the list. It only brings up the first item in the list.

Comment: I don't know what that means. You should show the code you're using now (as an edit to your question).

Comment: it creates a web server that pretty much is supposed to list whatever query you enter such as, http://t0mbst0n3:8080/search?q=cat+pictures where "cat+pictures" is your query. It then will list out about 10 entries in the command line and store the parts in lists. However if I return those lists it only pulls up the first entry of said list.

Comment: Your new code makes absolutely no sense at all. You need to go back to creating a dictionary in each loop, but then *append* it to a list, then *return that list*.